# Let r,s,u be binary relations in U ...Verify following proreperty;

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Which explanation to understand this do i need to learn ?

" if both relations r and s are transitive then the intersection of r and s is transitive too."

Comment: you might be right sir , I will remove this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
(a,b), (b,c) \in R \cap S
\implies
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
  (a,b), (b,c) \in R \overset{R \text{ transitive}}{\implies} (a,c) \in R \\
  (a,b), (b,c) \in S \overset{S \text{ transitive}}{\implies} (a,c) \in S \\
\end{array}
\right\}
\implies (a,c) \in R \cap S
$

Therefore, $R \cap S$ is also transitive.

Comment: thank you sir, that was very clear